# ROS Answers SE migration: publish error

Tags: ros, rosseral-arduino, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i am doing a project of robot dicking station. This program is for three infrared receivers and three infrared emitters, i don't know why it happened. Could anybody help me ?

```
#include <IRremote.h>
#include <IRremoteInt.h>

#include <ros.h>
#include <std_msgs/String.h>


ros::NodeHandle  nh;

std_msgs::String str_msg;
ros::Publisher st("state", &str_msg);


char state[10] = "cent-left";
char state_1[11] = "cent-right";
char state_2[10] = "cent-cent";
char state_3[11] = "right-left";
char state_4[12] = "right-right";
char state_5[11] = "right-cent";
char state_6[10] = "left-left";
char state_7[11] = "left-right";
char state_8[10] = "left-cent";


int RECV_PIN = 11;
int RECV_PIN_2= 9;
int RECV_PIN_1= 13;

IRrecv irrecv(RECV_PIN);
IRrecv irrecv1(RECV_PIN_1);
IRrecv irrecv2(RECV_PIN_2);

decode_results results;

void setup()
{
   irrecv.enableIRIn();
  irrecv1.enableIRIn();
  irrecv2.enableIRIn();
  nh.initNode();
  nh.advertise(st);




}

void loop()
{ 
  long Right=0xEF1F1509;
  long left=0xCC36FF5E;

  if (irrecv.decode(&results)) 
  { 
  long val2= results.value;  
     if(val2==0xEF1F1509)
    { 
       str_msg.data = state;
    } else if(val2==0xCC36FF5E)
    {
       str_msg.data = state_1;
    }
     else {
         str_msg.data = state_2;
         }       
       st.publish( &str_msg );
       
  }
  if (irrecv1.decode(&results))
  {
    long val=results.value;
    if (val==0xEF1F1509)
    {
    str_msg.data=state_3;
    } else
    if (val==0xCC36FF5E)
    {
    str_msg.data=state_4;
    }else
    {
      str_msg.data=state_5;
    }
    st.publish(&str_msg);
  }
    if (irrecv2.decode(&results))
  {
    long val1=results.value;
    if (val1==0xEF1F1509)
    {
    str_msg.data=state_6;
    } else
    if (val1==0xCC36FF5E)
    {
    str_msg.data=state_7;
    }else
    {
      str_msg.data=state_8;
    }
    st.publish(&str_msg);
  }
  nh.spinOnce();
  delay(1500);
}
```

Console:

```
[INFO] [WallTime: 1398132348.674181] ROS Serial Python Node
[INFO] [WallTime: 1398132348.682297] Connecting to /dev/ttyACM0 at 57600 baud
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1398132365.792995] Unable to sync with device; possible link problem or link software version mismatch such as hydro rosserial_python with groovy Arduino
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/155996/publish-error/) by [noel](https://answers.ros.org/users/15066/noel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-04-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not sure but documentation says to include ros.h as first:

> In order to use the rosserial libraries in your own code, you must first put
> include ros.h
> prior to including any other header files, e.g.

---

Originally posted by [afranceson](https://answers.ros.org/users/19838/afranceson/) with karma: 497 on 2014-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0